# python does not return value but print value..(sudoku search)

Tags: python, sudoku

```
def sudoku(puzzle):
    a,new=[],[]
    for i in range(9):
        c=[]
        for j in range(9):
            b=node(i,j)
            if puzzle[i][j]!=0:
                b.value=puzzle[i][j]
            c.append(b)
        a.append(c)
    l=0
    while get_empty(a)!=l:
        l=get_empty(a)
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].get_avail(a)

        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].delete(a)
    if goal(a):
        return board(a) 
    else:
        new.append(a)               
    while len(new)!=0:
        sud=new.pop(-1)
        em=get_empty(sud)
        s=em.pop()
        cand=s.get_avail(sud)
        for k in range(len(cand)):
            b=copy.deepcopy(sud)
            b[s.v][s.h].value=cand[k]
            l=0
            while len(get_empty(b))!=l:
                l=len(get_empty(b))
                for i in range(9):
                    for j in range(9):
                        if b[i][j].value==0:
                            b[i][j].get_avail(b)

                for i in range(9):
                    for j in range(9):
                        if b[i][j].value==0:
                            b[i][j].delete(b)                        
            if goal(b):
                return board(b)
            new.append(b)
```

This function does not `[return board(b)]` but when I tried without defining function, it 'print out' the solution[`print (board(b))]`. In the printing out case,
I just used from the second line to the last with replacing return with print.
I do not know how to fix this problem. please help.

```
import heapq,copy
grid,val={'1':[],'2':[],'3':[],'4':[],'5':[],'6':[],'7':[],'8':[],'9':   []},[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        if 0<=i<3 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['1'].append([i,j])
        elif 0<=i<3 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['2'].append([i,j])
        elif 0<=i<3 and 6<=j<9:
            grid['3'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['4'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['5'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 6<=j<9:
            grid['6'].append([i,j])
        elif 6<=i<9 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['7'].append([i,j])
        elif 6<=i<9 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['8'].append([i,j])
        else:
            grid['9'].append([i,j])
class node():
    def __init__(self,v,h):
        self.v=v
        self.h=h
        if 0<=i<3 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='1'
        elif 0<=i<3 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='2'
        elif 0<=i<3 and 6<=j<9:
            self.g='3'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='4'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='5'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 6<=j<9:
            self.g='6'
        elif 6<=i<9 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='7'
        elif 6<=i<9 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='8'
        else:
            self.g='9'
        self.choice=[]
        self.free=len(self.choice)
        self.value=0
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.free<other.free
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.free==other.free
    def get_avail(self,sud):
        i,j,k=self.v,self.h,self.g
        av=[]
        for x in range(9):
            if sud[x][j].value!=0:
                av.append(sud[x][j].value)
        for y in range(9):
            if sud[i][y].value!=0:
                av.append(sud[i][y].value)
            for x in range(9):
                v=sud[x][y]
                if v.g==k and v.value!=0:
                    av.append(v.value)
        avail=list(set(val)-set(av))
        if len(avail)==1:
            self.value=avail[0]
        self.choice=avail
        return avail
    def delete(self,sud):
        selff=self.choice
        other=[]
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if i==self.v or self.h==j or self.g==sud[i][j].g:
                    other=other+self.choice
        avail=list(set(selff)-set(other))
        if len(avail)==1:
            self.value=avail[0]
        return avail



def goal(sud):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if sud[i][j].value==0:
                return False
    return True
def board(sud):
    aa=[]
    for i in range(9):
        aaa=[]
        for j in range(9):
            aaa.append(sud[i][j].value)
        aa.append(aaa)
    return aa
def get_empty(sud):
    aa=[]
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if sud[i][j].value==0:
                aa.append(sud[i][j])
    heapq.heapify(aa)
    return aa
```

Here is the rest of the code for that sudoku. 
Hope there is no further abstractness or missing parts.
if necessary I can give examples of sudoku problems. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2IHm.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMV5d.jpg)

Comment: where is node() function and is puzzel square matrix?

Comment: There are three places where this function can exit.  Two are explicit return statements.  The third occurs when it is in the last while loop and len(new) == 0.  In that case the function falls out the bottom and returns None.  There are no print statements in this listing so the printing must occur somewhere else.  II don't know if this helps but without the rest of the program it's hard to go any deeper.

Comment: yes there are three ways and the problem is I already got the solution with print out command while I didn't get anything with return command. this rules out the failure of code case I think.

Comment: puzzle=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 9, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0],
 [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
 [9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
 [0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: How do you KNOW it doesn't return anything?  If it encounters a return statement it must return the value specified.  Instead of rewriting the program without defining a function, try printing the value.just before you return it, and print the value returned from the function call.  And you're still not giving us the whole program; I see no call to the sudoku() function..

Comment: I attached the screenshot of my idE, which PRINTS the solution while DO NOT RETURN anything. As I said, I just use the same command but not the first line(def sudoku(puzzle))